# problem with putting everything on the same line

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
"Hello World! I know all about \[ \int_1^7 \frac{dx}{x}\] and \[e^{\pi i}\].

\end{document}
```

i dont know how to make everything to same line

Comment: You are using display math (`\[` ... `\]`), which will always put the mathematics on a different line. Did you want inline math mode (`$` ... `$`)?

Comment: im new to latex and i dont know what the $ do. please explain

Comment: If you don't know, then what about reading some introductory material like »[LaTeX for complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)«?

Comment: There is *The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e*, which is available in [many different languages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/).

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$\int_1^7 \frac{dx}{x}$ and $e^{\pi i}$
```